# Can't use vue.js from django

Tags: django, vue.js, webpack

I introduced `vuejs` using webpack in `django`, but I can not use `vue` instances from `django` templates.

Looking at the chrome devtool, the transpiled js is loaded correctly, but shows `{{message}}`.

The following message is output on the console of chrome devtool.

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'hasOwnProperty.call (it, key)')

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Vue
```

This is my code.

`main.js`

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from '@/plugins/vuetify' // path to vuetify export

window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  vuetify,
}).$mount('#app')
```

`html`

```html
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example</title>
  </head>

  <body>
  {% verbatim %}
  <div id="app">
  {{ message }}
  </div>
  {% endverbatim %}

  {% render_bundle 'main' %}
  <script>
  var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
  message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
  })
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`log(django)`

```
django        | [09/Jan/2020 11:22:58] "GET /vue/ HTTP/1.1" 200 374
django        | [09/Jan/2020 11:22:58] "GET /static/webpack_bundles/main-ccb1054f18bba9ee992d.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

`urls.py`

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import signupfunc, loginfunc, listfunc, logoutfunc, vuefunc

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', signupfunc, name='signup'),
    path('login/', loginfunc, name='login'),
    path('list/', listfunc, name='list'),
    path('logout/', logoutfunc, name='logout'),
    path('vue/', vuefunc, name='vue'),
]
```

`vies.py`

```py
<snip>

def vuefunc(request):
    return render(request, 'vue.html')
```

Comment: @Parth Pandya Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

This might be a dumb question, but are you importing your `main.js` file from your template? It would look something like this:

```
<script src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>
```

Also, just as an aside, I use Vue with django and always list my own delimiter in the Vue code so I don't have to put `{% verbatim %}` tags around every variable. It looks something like this:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  delimiters: ['${', '}'],
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
```

and you can obviously pick whichever delimiters you want.